# How to provide link to styled image in a services feed

Tags: views, media, services

On our Drupal 7 site, we use the the services module to provide a feed for our internal news to pick up. With services, you create a view for all the data to provide. It is current giving the location of the original image for our images field (File: Path) that comes out http://oursite.com/sites/default/files/post.jpg. We want to provide a link to the styled image (already resized) that should look like https://oursite.com/sites/default/files/styles/downpage_art/public/field/image/solar_panels700x425.jpg?itok=P4VrgCIH. I don't see this as an option in the view we have for our feed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the [Image URL Formatter](https://www.drupal.org/project/image_url_formatter) module will help.

> Image URL formatter module offers 3 options that are not contained by views:
>
> - support Image styles
> - support multivalues, there is a "Multiple field settings" when image field is multivalue.

Comment: The module looked promising but the results came out as an empty array looking something like this:
array (
  0 => 
  stdClass::__set_state(array(
     'url' => 'http://oursite.com/sites/default/files/post.jpg',
     'caption' => 'Dick Post',
     'mimetype' => 'image/jpeg',
     'users_file_managed_mail' => 'author@oursite.com',
     'id' => '28815',
     'alt' => 'post',
     'title_text' => 'post',
     'fid' => '28815',
     'node_file_usage_nid' => '8900',
     'Images' => 
    array (
    ),
  )),

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend utilizing the [Views Datasource](http://drupal.org/project/views_datasource) module or the [Services Views](http://drupal.org/project/services_views) module. Both will allow you to set up a View to be consumed over a RESTful API. You can then use the View to easily select your image field(s), and the image style(s) to use.

Otherwise you'll need to implement [hook_menu()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_menu/7), and create a custom item with a `page_callback`. That page callback can then [programmatically generate an image style URL](http://tylerfrankenstein.com/user/4/code/programmatically-render-imagecache-preset-image-filefield-image-drupal), and output it with [drupal_json_output](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_json_output/7).